# How to get dynamically created UITextField (on top of UITableViewCell ) text value using tag?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield

I have one UITableView and in that UITableViewCell am dynamically creating "n" number of UITextFields. How do i get the values i entered into UITextField by using the tag?.

This is how i create UITextField dynamcally

```
-(UITextField *)displayTextfield:(NSUInteger)index{


    textField= [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15,40,cell.frame.size.width-30,cell.frame.size.height)];
    textField.placeholder=@"Text here";
    textField.tag=index;
    textField.delegate=self;

    textField.keyboardType=UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation;
    textField.textAlignment=UITextAlignmentLeft;
    textField.font= [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Neue Light" size:14];
    textField.textColor=[UIColor darkGrayColor];
    textField.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:245.0/255.0 green:245.0/255.0 blue:245.0/255.0 alpha:1];
    return textField;
}
```

This is how i tried to access UITextField Value but its crashing.

```
 NSString *text = [(UITextField *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:index] text];
```

Were `index` (tag) is getting from a for loop .

```
-[UITableViewCellContentView text]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fa8329d9360
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITableViewCellContentView text]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fa8329d9360'
```

Please help me to fix this

displayTextfield() calling from here

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView1 cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *MyIdentifier;
    if([[[selectedTabFields valueForKey:@"type"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"VARCHAR"]){
        MyIdentifier = @"CharCell";

    }else{
        MyIdentifier = @"IntCell";
    }

    cell= [tableView1 dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[dynamicCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                               reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;               

        [cell.contentView addSubview:[self displayTextfield:indexPath.row]];

    }

return cell;
}
```

Comment: Where do you call `displayTextfield` function? Can you also show us that part?

Comment: @ozgur updating question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zeroth index in `cell.contentView.subviews` is already taken by a special view named `UITableViewCellContentView` so the following line doesn't return a UITextField when `indexPath.row` is `0`:

```
>>> NSLog("%@", [cell.contentView viewWithTag:0])
<UITableViewCellContentView: 0x7fb7c2eb1cd0; frame = (0 0; 320 43.5); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7fb7c2eb22a0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fb7c2eb1e40>
```

Change your tag value to something greater and this should fix the issue:

```
[cell.contentView addSubview:[self displayTextfield:indexPath.row + 1]];
```

so when you need to get the UITextField again:

```
NSString *text = [(UITextField *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:indexPath.row + 1] text];
```

Comment: let me try now itself

Answer (score 1):

Fix your function's first line to be:

```
UITextField * textField= [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15,40,cell.frame.size.width-30,cell.frame.size.height)];
```

Secondly, assign tag +1 to the textfield so it will be non-zero:

```
[cell.contentView addSubview:[self displayTextfield:indexPath.row + 1]];
```

Lastly, before accessing the textfield text property, make sure it is actually a textfield and that the view exist:

```
NSString * textFieldText = nil;
UIView * view = [cell.contentView viewWithTag:index];
if(view && [view isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
    UITextField * textField = (UITextField *)view;
    textFieldText = [textField text];
}

if(textFieldText) {
    // Use text here...
}
```

Comment: @Bangalore My pleasure, by using the code I wrote in my last point, you will 100% avoid crashes...